# nan:nan in Background of Field in PDF form

Tags: javascript, pdf, time

I have a field which calculates the total hours and minutes for a freelance during the day based on how much they have worked. My issue with this is that before any times are inserted there is the following text always visible in the field (nan:nan) I have below my code I am using, can someone please let me know how to make this not visible, thanks.

```
function Min2HHMM(nMinutes) {
// convert minutes to HH:MM string and returns formatted time string
return util.printf("%,001.0f:%,202.0f", Math.floor(nMinutes / 60), nMinutes % 60);
}

var T1 = this.getField("Start_Mon_01").value;
var T2 = this.getField("Finish_Mon_01").value;
var T3 = this.getField("Start_Mon_02").value;
var T4 = this.getField("Finish_Mon_02").value;


var start = T1.split(":");
var startmins1 = parseInt(start[0] * 60,10) + parseInt(start[1],10);

var finish = T2.split(":");
var finishmins1 = parseInt(finish[0] * 60,10) + parseInt(finish[1],10);

var start = T3.split(":");
var startmins2 = parseInt(start[0] * 60,10) + parseInt(start[1],10);

var finish = T4.split(":");
var finishmins2 = parseInt(finish[0] * 60,10) + parseInt(finish[1],10);

var timeDiff = finishmins1 - startmins1 + finishmins2 - startmins2;
event.value = Min2HHMM(timeDiff);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several ways:

```
function getNum(str) {
   return isNaN(str) || str=="" ? 0:parseInt(str,10);
}

var T1 = getNum(this.getField("Start_Mon_01").value);
var T2 = getNum(this.getField("Finish_Mon_01").value);
var T3 = getNum(this.getField("Start_Mon_02").value);
var T4 = getNum(this.getField("Finish_Mon_02").value);
```

OR

`return isNaN(nMinutes) ? "0:00": util.printf("%,001.0f:%,202.0f", Math.floor(nMinutes / 60), nMinutes % 60);`

Or

`event.value = isNaN(timeDiff)?"0:00": Min2HHMM(timeDiff);`

should work.

Also no need to parsint something you multiply.

`parseInt(start[0] * 60,10)` is the same as `start[0] * 60`